# Properties Window VS2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022, multiple-projects

I am new at web programming, I'm trying to create a MPA with TypeScript Angular Template & ASP.NET Core Web API project with VS2022 but I am stuck almost at the very beginning.

I am trying to select the launch.json debugger but when I right click the project for some reason all I get is 2 options "Build & Deploy" I cannot get the project’s configuration properties window to show me the "Debugging" option no matter what.

I already tried to recreate the project tons of times, uninstall everything (npm, VS, .Net SDK, Angualar CLI, node.JS) but still, I tried in three different computers and still the same issue. I also tried to find similar topic but no luck.

[image: VS 2022 Options Window]

is there any other way to this without having to use the properties window or how do I make the properties window to display the debugging option

Please any help provided will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround of sorts, seems the problem with what I want to do has to do with the following line inside the code of the Angular project:

Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.5.45-alpha"

If I edit the version as follows the settings will give me the option for Debugging

Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.2.0-alpha"

[VS2022](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRZJW.png)

I guess solves partially the problem as now I can assign the launch.json as the debugger option but I am still wondering why this doesn't work with the SDK updated version given by default when creating a new project.